# Pls help with this prompt. I've been struggling last 2 days with this and its due tomorrow

Tags: potentiometer, buzzer

"Use an Arduino, two potentiometers, and an alarm. Make one of the potentiometers act like a volume control, and make the other potentiometer control the tone that the alarm makes."
I added what I have so far. I'm not sure how to control the volume

[image]

Comment: that is a good start ..  the code should be added as text, not as a picture ... the `tone()` function has no volume control ... perhaps you are supposed to build a volume control circuit

Comment: @Mahmodol this site is a question and answer site ... its purpose is to answer questions ... if you ask a clear question, then someone will try to answer it

Comment: Post a schematic as you have it wired, part of your frizzy picture is not even connected. With such short notice I will be surprised if you get it resolved in time. When you are given an assignment it is best to start ASAP, waiting until the end causes problems like this and missed assignments.

Comment: Welcome to SE/Arduino! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. -- What have you tried to read the values of the potentiometers? -- Please [edit] your question, don't add a comment. This is not a forum. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use the other potentiometer as a variable resistor. Instead of connecting to pins 1 and 3 (to control tone), Use the 2nd pin of the potentiometer to make a voltage divider. From the 3rd pin go to a + on a buzzer. I don't see the reason to have the circuit connected the way you have. if you want to control the tone with potentiometer, connect it to stable 5v, and connect the second pin with any analog pins that is configured as input. Then, use map function, and map the voltage, accordingly to the tone you'd like to use.